# Ios swift spacing between views and/or margins in percentage %

Tags: ios, swift, spacing

there is a way to set horizontal space between 2 view or between 1 view and one margin in percentage?
I can set horizontal spacing or trailing space to superview or leading space to superview with constanst value (in pixels or some similar unit).

My personal solution was put a view A between what i want to pad (ie view B) and margin then i set view A width equals to superview and 0.3 (ie for 30%) at moltiplier.

Answer (score 1):

Each constraint in iOS has the following format

> item1.attribute1 = multiplier × item2.attribute2 + constant

So, when you set e.g. spacing with constant value you define that `constant` variable, and `multiplier` is set to 1 (no sense).

To set e.g. spacing in percentage you need to edit `multiplier` value, let say to 0.3 for 30% (or could be 1.3). You can do it in Interface builder, just select you constraint and define multiplier value. (from document outline or directly from IB)

Experiment with it, and also First/Second item.